# Is it possible to have 3 or more applications visible to the user on an android device?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-9.0-pie, split-screen, split-screen-multitasking

I am writing multiple android applications. I want to have my screen divided in two or more places so that the user can view 3 or more apps simultaneously.

In other operating systems like Linux or Windows, one can view as many applications as one wants by dynamically resizing the application window.
Is it possible to have this in android?

I tried opening apps with multi-window support introduced from API level 24, but it seems to only support 2 apps simultaneously. Can this functionality be extended to 3 or more apps?

I tried forcing my app activity to fixed dimensions, so that I could hard code the dimensions of each app in order to fit them all on screen, but when the app launched it utilized the whole screen. Is there a way around this?

Comment: No there is no way to show 3 apps at once , I heard that galaxy fold will support 3 apps simultaneously .

Comment: @Mike Thanks for that. Could you please point me to the resources that would help me make these apps?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do it in Samsung 9 (Android version 9). You open "Edge" menu and drag and drop window in screen. If you have different device you can try to use Samsung device farm: https://program.developer.samsung.com/cloud-device-farm-lp/

[image]